AG Grid numpad keys when editing cell
I have a custom cell editor and when I press + or NumpadAdd key on my keyboard, the agInit method with params in the custom cell editor gets called and the params always gives me ‘+’ as the value in the eventKey property. I need to differentiate in the cell editor whether standard + was called or NumpadAdd was called. Is there a way to get it in the cell editor?

In Angular, you can use $event.code to distinguish different keys.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-keyboard-monitor',
  templateUrl: './keyboard-monitor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./keyboard-monitor.component.scss']
})
export class KeyboardMonitorComponent {
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(`code: ${event.code}`);
  }
}





key
key code




Normal +
+
Equal


Numpad +
+
NumpadAdd




This is not useful since aggrid agInit gets called before the angular keydown event is listened. I need to know which key was pressed in the aggrid cell editor agInit
